# Limit of a definite integral $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Given the integral:
$$S=\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}$$
I get from MAPLE this result:
$$\lim_{a\to \infty}S=0$$
My question is: how can I prove this result?
Thanks.

Comment: It's a sin to write `sin` instead of `\sin`. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By a change of variables, you can rewrite your integral above as

$$S= \int_{-a^2}^{a^2} \frac{1}{a}\frac{\sin u}{u} du$$

which we can rewrite as $$\int_0^{a^2}\frac{2}{a} \frac{\sin u}{u} du = \frac{2}{a}\int_0^{a^2} \frac{\sin u}{u} du$$

Now the limit of the integral as $a \rightarrow \infty $ is $\pi/2$ (this can be proved using knowledge of the Dirichlet Kernel and Riemann-Lebesgue), while the limit as $a \rightarrow \infty$ of $2/a$ is zero. Therefore the limit of $S$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$ is zero.

Comment: Just to note that all you need to do to prove the result requested is to show that $\int_0^{a^2} \frac{\sin u}{u} du$ is bounded, which can be done without evaluating the integral.

Comment: @MarkBennet This can be done by integration by parts I believe.

Comment: I was thinking that the interval of integration could be divided into pieces of length $\pi$, which gives the sum of alternating series whose terms tend to zero.